# How can I tell if a Hibernate entity is read-only or not

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence

I've made an entity read-only after retrieving it using:

```
Session session = (Session)entityManager.getDelegate();
session.setReadOnly( entity, makeReadOnly );
```

I'd like to be able to test whether this object and its lazy-loaded children are, in fact, read-only programmatically but I don't see any API to do that. Does such an API exist?

Update: I'm using Hibernate 3.3.1

Comment: just curious, is this for unit testing or you would like this in live code? and why do you need it?

Comment: @aishwarya, I want to verify how lazily loaded entities work when the parent is set to read-only. I also want to see how child entities behave if they've already been loaded (either lazily or not) before setting the parent to read-only. I'd basically only need it while debugging through some of the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's  [Session.isReadOnly(Object entityOrProxy)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#isReadOnly%28java.lang.Object%29) for that.

edit:
Ugly hack for 3.3.1:

```
//usual imports
//....
import org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl;
import org.hibernate.engine.EntityEntry;
import org.hibernate.engine.Status;
import org.hibernate.engine.StatefulPersistenceContext;


Session session = (Session)entityManager.getDelegate();

SessionImpl sessImpl = (SessionImpl) session;
if (((StatefulPersistenceContext) sessImpl.getPersistenceContext()).getEntry(entity).getStatus() == Status.READ_ONLY) {
    dosomething
};
```

Comment: Ahh.. That's there in 3.5 but not in 3.3.1 that we're using but I can look at the code in the 3.5 implementation and use that. Thanks..

Comment: @ChrisWilliams ah, ok didn't know it's 3.3.1. Edited my answer, it includes lots of ugly casting though.

Comment: I should've checked back after I accepted! I just came back to post my the solution for 3.3.1 and you beat me to it. Thanks!